# Why there is a pythonw window generated when mine QProgressDialog window was auto closed?

Tags: pyqt, progressdialog

I am new to both pyqt and python so I'm sure that my question would seem stupid, so thank you for reading and answer it. It is really helpful.

Here is my source code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
import sys  

QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(QTextCodec.codecForName("utf8"))
class Prog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Prog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.start_P()
    def start_P(self):
        progressDialog=QProgressDialog(self)  
        progressDialog.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)  
        progressDialog.setMinimumDuration(5)  
        progressDialog.setWindowTitle(self.tr("请等待"))  
        progressDialog.setLabelText(self.tr("拷贝..."))
        progressDialog.setCancelButtonText(self.tr("取消"))
        progressDialog.setRange(0,100)  
        progressDialog.setAutoClose(True)

        for i in range(101):  
            progressDialog.setValue(i)  
            QThread.msleep(10)  
            if progressDialog.wasCanceled():  
                return
        self.connect(progressDialog,SIGNAL("closed()"))
def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pp = Prog()
    pp.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are some Chinese characters, but it's irrelevant. The strange part is when I execute this program I would get a window of progress dialog, that is what I want. But when it is auto closed a pythonw window generated automatically.

I was curious about why this pythonw window was generated and want to know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are creating your `QProgressDialog` as child of a `QDialog`, checkout the line that says `progressDialog=QProgressDialog(self)`. Checkout how this example works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

#---------
# IMPORT
#---------
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

#---------
# MAIN
#---------
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    _stopped = False

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True

    def start(self):
        self._stopped = False

        super(MyThread, self).start()

    def run(self):           
        for progressNumber in range(101):
            self.progress.emit(progressNumber)
            self.msleep(22)

            if self._stopped:
                return

class MyWindow(QtGui.QProgressDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.threadProgress = MyThread(self)
        self.threadProgress.progress.connect(self.setValue)

    def stop(self):
        self.threadProgress.stop()

    def start(self):
        self.threadProgress.start()

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("utf8")
    QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(codec)

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.setWindowTitle(main.tr("请等待"))  
    main.setLabelText(main.tr("拷贝..."))
    main.setCancelButtonText(main.tr("取消"))
    main.setRange(0,100)
    main.canceled.connect(main.stop)
    main.show()
    main.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I cannot fully understand the code but it's really works!!!Could you please recommend some books or blogs or web about pyqt? I only know the pyqt4 Tutorial website, the example is helpful there but lack of orgnized background knowledge.

Comment: @CangJiaxuan I think that's a good place to start, I also found the Qt Docs http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/classes.html quite useful